# Legitimate use cases for writable etc/passwd files

Tags: linux, privilege-escalation

I´m learning about linux privilege escalation via a writable /etc/passwd file and was wondering how common that actualy is?

Are there any use cases where a regular user might have (or even needs) write access to the /etc/passwd file or is this more of a artificial thing for security courses that is rarely seen in real life?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are there any use cases where a regular user might have (or even
> needs) write access to the /etc/passwd file

No.

Regular users need *read access* for things like having `ls -l` print out the owner of a file.  That need for read access drove the split where `/etc/passwd` is readable, but has no password hashes, and `/etc/shadow` contains those password hashes but should never be readable to anyone but `root`.

> is this more of a artificial thing for security courses that is rarely seen in real life?

Yes.  It's an easy way to demonstrate how simple changes can affect security, but writable `/etc/passwd` isn't something you see 'in the wild'